# Making request to multiple links using urllib.request

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a request to multiple links from Yahoo Finance then return array of `Income Statement`, `Balance Sheet` and `Cash Flow`, respectively. I found myself stuck in a lot of `for loops`. I'm wondering if there a better version to this code below:

```
def scrapper(symbol):

    htmls = []
    soup = []
    gen_table = []

    IS = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}+Income+Statement&annual".format(symbol)
    BS = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}+Balance+Sheet&annual".format(symbol)
    CF = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}+Cash+Flow&annual".format(symbol)
    urls = [IS, BS, CF]

    # read each link in urls
    for url in urls:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
            htmls.append(response.read())
    # parse data with BeautifulSoup
    for html in htmls:
        soup.append(BeautifulSoup(html))
    # store income statement, balance sheet and cash flow into soup
    for s in soup:
        gen_table.append(s.find_all("table", class_="yfnc_tabledata1"))

    return gen_table
```

Comment: Why not create a function that takes one URL and handles that separately?

Comment: The only reason you are using loops is because you are handling each stage in a separate loop; you could just handle each step in one loop. But delegating it to a function would make that clearer.

Comment: Create a function that takes a single url as an argument and returns the arrays like @MartijnPieters mentioned.  Just use include all the urls you need parsed in a list, run a for each loop on the list, then pass each url's html code into the parsing function which will gladly output what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I might do it this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

def fetch_table(symbol, table):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s={}+{}&annual".format(symbol, table)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        result = response.read()
    result = BeautifulSoup(result)
    result = result.find_all("table", class_="yfnc_tabledata1")
    return result

def scrapper(symbol):
    return [fetch_table(symbol, table)
            for table in (
                "Income+Statement",
                "Balance+Sheet",
                "Cash+Flow")]

print (scrapper("X"))
```

Comment: I like how there is less `for loop` in this code. Thanks :)